# Read and visualize multiple .ply in PCL

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I am new to Point Cloud Library (PCL) and C++ programming. I have a simple code to load multiple .ply files and visualize them using the code below. It iterates through a loop to load multiple .ply files given as the arguments (say test0.ply, test1.ply ... test99.ply) and visualize them one after another. I need to visualize them as fast as possible possible like as if they are frames of a video.

This is what I've tried so far. Previously `spinOnce()` was placed outside of my loop and I was not seeing anything. But then I just moved it inside the loop and iterate through the list and try to visualize them. Now it works, however, it is VERY slow (only 1 FPS?!!)

What is going wrong? How should I change the code to show models with a faster pace?

```
#include <iostream>

#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/io/ply_io.h>
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/console/parse.h>
#include <pcl/common/transforms.h>
#include <pcl/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h>

// This function displays the help
void showHelp(char *program_name)
{
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Usage: " << program_name << " cloud_filename.[pcd|ply]" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "-h: Show this help." << std::endl; 
}

// Main function
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    // Show help
    if(pcl::console::find_switch(argc,argv,"-h") || pcl::console::find_switch(argc,argv,"--help"))
    {
        showHelp(argv[0]);
        return 0; 
    }

    // Fetch point cloud filename in arguments | Works with PLY files
    std::vector<int> filenames;

    filenames = pcl::console::parse_file_extension_argument(argc,argv,".ply");



    // Visualization 
    printf("\n Point cloud colors :\n"
        " \t white \t = \t original point cloud \n");

    pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer viewer(" Point Cloud Visualizer");
    viewer.setBackgroundColor(0.05,0.05,0.05,0); // Set background to a dark grey

    // Load file | Works with PLY files
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr source_cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> ());

for(int i=0; i<argc-1; i++)
{

cout<<argv[filenames[i]]<<endl;

        if(pcl::io::loadPLYFile(argv[filenames[i]],*source_cloud) < 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Error loading point cloud " << argv[filenames[i+1]] << std::endl << std::endl;
            showHelp (argv[i+1]);
            return -1;
        }


    // Define R,G,B colors for the point cloud 
    pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerRGBField<pcl::PointXYZRGB> rgb(source_cloud);
//  pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerCustom<pcl::PointXYZ> source_cloud_color_handler(source_cloud,255,255,255); // White

    // We add the point cloud to the viewer and pass the color handler 
if(i!=0){
    viewer.removePointCloud("original_cloud"+(i-1));
}
    viewer.addPointCloud(source_cloud,rgb,"original_cloud"+i);
    viewer.setPointCloudRenderingProperties(pcl::visualization::PCL_VISUALIZER_POINT_SIZE,2,"original_cloud"+i);

viewer.spinOnce(100, true);
    }

        return 0;
    } // End main()
```

Comment: What is it that you have problem with? What have you tried and how the results differ from what you'd expect?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to pipeline specially in the network case. Maybe while a new file is being delivered we start visualizing the previous one, assuming we have enough buffered data.

Comment: For animation, "as fast as possible" is not usually what you want. You really want to display each frame for some specific duration, like 1/24 of a second.

Comment: @Alex Right. Whatever the loop allows me. But currently nothing is being shown.

Comment: @Alex I want to find out the FPS and evaluate how fast PCL rendering and visualization can be.

Comment: How fast is the loop going? Is is plausible that you are rendering one frame on top of another so fast that you can't see anything but the last frame? Try adding some kind of delay after each call to `viewer.spinOnce`.

Comment: Also, look at the [parameters of `spinOnce`](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1visualization_1_1_p_c_l_visualizer.html#a896556f91ba6b45b12a9543a2b397193). The default values for `time` and `forceRedraw` could be pre-empting the rendering.

Comment: btw, is it correct I put `viewer.spinOnce()` outside the loop? Is it needed to visualize? Why is it inside a while loop itself?!

Comment: @Alex OK. I just moved `spinOnce()` inside my loop and now I can see one after another. However, it is VERY slow (1 FPS?!) . I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your previous animation loop was running as fast as possible:

```
while(!viewer.wasStopped()){
    viewer.spinOnce();
}
```

That probably meant it was rendering the images faster than you could see. If you want maximum speed, you could put in some timing code there to measure how long each frame takes.

Now your animation loop is the same as your file-reading loop, so each frame will take at least as long as it takes to read a file from disk/SSD with `pcl::io::loadPLYFile`. It's not surprising that the filesystem, storage, file interpretation, and rendering together would take about 1 second per file.

If you want a smooth animation, put a delay in your original, fast loop:

```
import <thread>

while(!viewer.wasStopped()){
    viewer.spinOnce();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(0.04s);
}
```

Comment: Your are absolutely right on the disk delay. It is because of the disk delay. We might need to do a buffering or maybe some pipeline.

Comment: Compiler picks on your code: `This requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011`.

Comment: btw, no method named as `wasStoppedspinOnce()`